# Introductory phrases and commas

Tags: commas

Online grammar checkers verify this sentence as correct:

> I told him “I just put commas where my brain pauses.” He said, “You need
>   to get your brain examined.”

The online software seems to be fine with or without a comma in the first line, but it insists that I use a comma in the second line after *'He said'*.

My question is: Why do I not need a comma after the phrase *'I told him'* in the first line? Isn't that an introductory phrase too?

Comment: In the first sentence, a comma is optional between '... him' and '"I just put ..."'.  (I would have put a comma there because I would assume the writer was quoting himself, but this may not be so: the writer could be merely paraphrasing himself.  I would *not* put a comma in the first sentence if it had been written "I told him that "I just put....")  In the second sentence, the comma is standard between 'He said,' and '"You need..."' because the writer was quoting the person responding to the first sentence.

Comment: @tautophile: In present-day English, the quotation marks indicate a direct quote, without paraphrase. (Sometimes this is a bit of a conceit -- sometimes the quote has been reconstructed or cleaned up or whatnot -- but if you're using quotation marks then you're marking it as quotation rather than paraphrase, and the other punctuation must be chosen accordingly.)

Comment: The choice of introductory punctuation with direct speech and other quotes is now reckoned by most to include zero punctuation (after an initial speech tag and before the opening inverted commas) as well as the traditional comma and colon. I feel free to choose whichever I think most fitting. << The notice read: 'No picnicking on the grass.' >> << He replied thoughtfully, "Are you _quite_ sure that's your toupee?" >> << Mycroft riposted without a pause "How would _you_ know?" >>  // While I think I'd prefer the [zero; comma] option chosen here, I'd not consider other permutations incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that online grammar checkers do not actually understand English. Machine intelligence has come a very long way in the past thirty years and more, but it still has a long way yet to go.

The software that you're consulting recognizes a few simple patterns, but it can't *really* tell when a comma is and is not appropriate. If you give it a case where "he said" should *not* be followed by a comma, I bet it will wrongly flag it:

> He said "everything he was required to", according to his lawyer.